# Default callout fill in the color of the left accessory view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a way to get the left accessory view of the callout to just fill in the rest of the view with a background color?
[image: Current callout]

I am currently just doing it with this

```
let leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "leaf32"))
leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
anView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftView
```

I want to have the background fill like the blue in the apple maps default callout. [image: Apples map callout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
let leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "leaf32"))
leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
anView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftView
```

Comment: ahmed with the fire solutions